# Tomar el valor de una variable (calculada en un módulo) en un formulario VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Muy buenas!

Resulta que tengo un documento de excel con un formulario donde introduzco información variada sobre un presupuesto, donde según los servicios a realizar se calcula el coste.

En el formulario cuento con 2 botones. Uno de ellos me  genera una ventana emergente para ver el precio final al instante. El segundo de ellos, me genera una ficha con toda la info del presupuesto.

La cuestión es que para calcular el precio, lo realizo en un módulo, para no repetir el código en cada uno de los botones, sin embargo no consigo llamar al valor obtenido en el módulo para utilizarlo con las macros asignadas a los botones del formulario.

He visto algún hilo en el foro con las variables Public, pero no he encontrado solución de momento.

La estructura del código es la siguiente:

El Formulario está constituido por varías cuestiones que se respondan con Option Buttons, por lo cual se devuelven valores True or False.

---Botón Coste del Formulario---

Sub Boton_Coste_Click()

Calculo_Coste.Coste_Proyecto

MsgBox "El coste del proyecto es " & coste & " €"

---

Después en el Módulo donde se encuentra el cálculo del coste como tal se toman los valores de las OptionBox y alguna ComboBox para proceder al calculo.

---Módulo del cálculo del coste---

Sub Coste_Proyecto()

Dim coste as integer

If factor1 = true then
Coste = Coste+10
End If

.....

End sub

---

Por último tengo otro botón que toma el valor de otras variables introducidas en Text.Box para generar un documento y se introduce tmbn el Coste como valor final.

La cuestión es que no haga falta comprobar el coste del proyecto para generar ese documento final.

Ahora, no se si tengo que declarar el valor de las OptionBox en el formulario, acabo de caer mientras redactaba la pregunta. Entiendo que una OptionBox denominada por ejemplo "ModificacionDiseño" no puedo identificarla como una variable publica, y en el formulario darle el valor de esa Option Box a una variable...

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Amigo, sin código ni ejemplo ni datos ni nada, es imposible dar una respuesta. Pero claramente es declarar la variable como pública.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Muy buenas compañero, acabo de modificar para dar un poco más de nociones de como está estructurado el código, el cual realmente no es complejo, pero así quedará más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, pues como bien comento en la pregunta, mientras redactaba mi duda me di cuenta del hecho de que estaba intentando usar el valor de una OptionBox directamente en un Módulo, cuando lo que debía de hacer era en primer lugar declarar una variable pública a la que darle el valor de la OptionBox para depués ya poder usar ese valor.

Mi error era declarar el nombre de la propia OptionBox como Public.

Se nota que tengo poca experiencia, de todo se aprende.